# The ^ (bitwise XOR) in C++ with Boolean

Tags: c++, boolean, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I ran across a code challenge.  After I finished it I looked at the other answers.  I saw an answer that I am struggling to comprehend.

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN // This tells Catch to provide a main() - only do this in one cpp file
#include "catch.hpp"

bool willYou(bool young, bool beautiful, bool loved)
{
    return (young & beautiful) ^ loved;
}

TEST_CASE("willYou are computed", "[willYou]")
{
    REQUIRE(willYou(true, true, true) == false);
    REQUIRE(willYou(true, false, true) == true);
    REQUIRE(willYou(false, false, false) == false);
    REQUIRE(willYou(false, false, true) == true);
}
```

In case you want the information provided for the challenge (I don't think its necessary here) this is it.

```
Once Mary heard a famous song, and a line from it stuck in her head. That line was "Will you still love me when I'm no longer young and beautiful?". Mary believes that a person is loved if and only if he/she is both young and beautiful, but this is quite a depressing thought, so she wants to put her belief to the test.

Knowing whether a person is young, beautiful and loved, find out if they contradict Mary's belief.

A person contradicts Mary's belief if one of the following statements is true:

they are young and beautiful but not loved;
they are loved but not young or not beautiful.
Example

For young = true, beautiful = true, and loved = true, the output should be
willYou(young, beautiful, loved) = false.

Young and beautiful people are loved according to Mary's belief.

For young = true, beautiful = false, and loved = true, the output should be
willYou(young, beautiful, loved) = true.

Mary doesn't believe that not beautiful people can be loved.

Input/Output

[execution time limit] 0.5 seconds (cpp)

[input] boolean young

[input] boolean beautiful

[input] boolean loved

[output] boolean

true if the person contradicts Mary's belief, false otherwise.
```

What I am failing to grasp is how the ^ operator is used here to get the desired Boolean result?  I created those test using [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2).  From [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitwise-operators-in-c-cpp/) it simply states...

> The ^ (bitwise XOR) in C or C++ takes two numbers as operands and does XOR on every bit of two numbers. The result of XOR is 1 if the two bits are different.

Well, pretty sure true and false here would be 1 and 0.  So what I assumed was in the first test case would return 1 or true, but it is false or 0?  If all are true, why is it false?  I get that the story is trying to explain this here.  But in the story it is saying if young and beautiful, then you are loved.  I'm not sure if I am misunderstanding that statement, or if it's just bad explanation (I'm starting to think it's just bad).  Anyhow, I need help trying to understand this operator more and basically grasp what all this means.  I am just all but lost here.

Comment: it sounds like you had trouble understanding the question, not anything about the XOR operator. To be clear, are you saying you don't understand the stipulated requirement that `willYou(true, true, true) == false` ?

Comment: No, I understood that, or else I would of not stumbled upon someone else's answer which was `return (young & beautiful) ^ loved;` That's the part that stumps me because of the use of the ^ here.  The first test is saying if all are true then it should return false.  I get that.  But my code had nothing to do with the bitwise operator.  I come to find out the challenge appears to be about this operator and using it.  So, that is what I am trying to understand is its usage and why to use it for something like this.

Comment: do you understand that `(true & true) ^ true` gives `false` ?

Comment: No, and that's the point I am making and trying to grasp.

Comment: **Bitwise Exclusive-Or (XOR)
There is no boolean operator counterpart to bitwise exclusive-or, but there is a simple explanation. The exclusive-or operation takes two inputs and returns a 1 if either one or the other of the inputs is a 1, but not if both are. That is, if both inputs are 1 or both inputs are 0, it returns 0. Bitwise exclusive-or, with the operator of a caret, ^, performs the exclusive-or operation on each pair of bits. Exclusive-or is commonly abbreviated XOR.**
https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html

Comment: OK, the definition of XOR is:  true^true = false, false^false = false, true^false = true, false^true = true

Comment: "if both inputs are 1 or both inputs are 0, it returns 0"

Comment: Is that the best explanation to this from what I just posted?  Is that literally all there is to this with bool?  I wouldn't have posted this if I found that site but I just discovered it.

Comment: "best" is hard to quantify . You could look up features of the C++ language either in the C++ Standard or on cppreference.com  ,other random websites are often the blind leading the blind

Comment: @Milliorn Could your rather lengthy question be shortened to something more like *"Why does `(true & true) ^ true` evaluate to `false`?"* Your question would be much clearer if you started with that instead of the story of how you came across it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get what you are trying to ask. I saw the comments section trying to explain you what a XOR does and it was kind of funny. Anyway,

The problem states that, Mary's belief was: *"if you are young and beautiful, you are loved"*. Our goal is to contradict Mary and show her that there were times when someone was loved but did not have one of the two or both the qualities, *OR* if someone did **have** those qualities but was not loved.

**In a nutshell**, our aim is to contradict her beliefs.

The output of the `willYou()` function is to check *if* we can contradict Mary or not. Maybe you might have solved this question by taking in various cases and having an output for each. The solution mentioned in your question is a generic one.

The XOR operator returns 1 if there are an odd number of 1's in the expression.
For instance:

1. if `young` = 1 and `beautiful` = 1, their AND is 1 and their XOR with loved = 1 is 0(*i.e.* false) and hence it **does not** contradict Mary.
2. if `young` = 0 and `beautiful` = 1, their AND is 0 and their XOR with loved = 1 is 1(*i.e.* true) and hence it **does** contradict Mary.

Similarly, one can form this for other cases as well.

The solver must've used the "passer/inverter" property of XOR. Whenever the outputs were in Mary's favour, it inverted the answer to yield us `false` meaning we cannot contradict her. I think it would make our lives easier to say that it is just a creative solution made by someone and maybe not a mind-boggling problem(not trying to be condescending at all here).

Comment: **In a nutshell, our aim is to contradict her beliefs**.
That right there made more sense than all the comments posted.  If that is the case I can see 
` return (young & beautiful) ^ loved;
` 
is used the way it was used.

Comment: **if young = 1 and beautiful = 1, their AND is 1 and their XOR with loved = 1 is 0(i.e. false) and hence it does not contradict Mary.** This explains the first test result which was what was confusing me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [in]equality operators ('==' as xnor, and '!=' as xor);

bool a,b;

...

bool c=a==b;//xnor

bool d=a!=b;//xor